# Flutter: 'Future<PDFDocument>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm attempting to make a page that displays a PDF from assets when the page is opened. The PDF loads, but throws the error in the title just before it loads every time. I'm pretty sure that it has to do with how the function is called, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

My code example:

```
class Calendar2020PDFScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Calendar2020PDFScreenState();
}

class _Calendar2020PDFScreenState extends State<Calendar2020PDFScreen> {
  bool _isLoading = false, _isInit = true;
  PDFDocument document;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          leading: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
          title: Center(
              child: Text(
            'MCHD',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          )),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {
                showSearch(context: context, delegate: DataSearch());
              },
            ) //IconButton
          ], //,Widget>[]
        ), //Appbar
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: _isInit
                    ? loadFromAssets() // Executes loadFromAssets function if _isInit is true
                    : _isLoading
                        ? Center(
                            child:
                                CircularProgressIndicator(), //Shows indicator if _isLoading is true
                          ) //Center
                        : PDFViewer(
                            document: document,
                          ), //PDFViewer
              ), //Center
            ), //Expanded
          ], //<Widget>[]
        ), //Column
      ), //Scaffold
    ); //MaterialApp
  }

  Future<PDFDocument> loadFromAssets() async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        _isInit = false; //remove text
        _isLoading = true; //show loading
      });
      document = await PDFDocument.fromAsset("assets/PDFs/calendars_2020.pdf");
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false; //remove loading
      });
      return document;
    } catch (err) {
      print('Caught error: $err');
    } //catch
  } //Future
}
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Calendar2020PDFScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Calendar2020PDFScreenState();
}

class _Calendar2020PDFScreenState extends State<Calendar2020PDFScreen> {
  bool _isLoading = false, _isInit = true;
  PDFDocument document;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    loadFromAssets();
    // this is where you load your asssets
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          leading: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
          title: Center(
              child: Text(
            'MCHD',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          )),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {
                showSearch(context: context, delegate: DataSearch());
              },
            ) //IconButton
          ], //,Widget>[]
        ), //Appbar
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: _isLoading
                        ? Center(
                            child:
                                CircularProgressIndicator(), //Shows indicator if _isLoading is true
                          ) //Center
                        : PDFViewer(
                            document: document,
                          ), //PDFViewer
              ), //Center
            ), //Expanded
          ], //<Widget>[]
        ), //Column
      ), //Scaffold
    ); //MaterialApp
  }

  Future<PDFDocument> loadFromAssets() async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true; //show loading
      });
      document = await PDFDocument.fromAsset("assets/PDFs/calendars_2020.pdf");
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false; //remove loading
      });
      return document;
    } catch (err) {
      print('Caught error: $err');
    } //catch
  } //Future
}
```

may be you should check out this, where you load you assets first in the initState and the while this method loads the circular progress and after loading it will give you the desired output, did not try out but arranged it. 
give a try let me know if any problem.
or else you can use the future builder if there is simultaneous change.

Just check the null condition for the document.

Thanks.